# Python inbuilt HTMLcalendar

Tags: python, django

How I can display the calendar on certain datetime data which are already saved into the database? I am trying to use python inbuilt HTMLCalendar but yet not found any good tutorial how to use it or which calendar app will be better for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Python inbuilt calendar is very simple, I don't think you need any tutorials.

Since Python output the calendar html, I think you can leave a param in django template and use python to fill it.

```
import calendar
myCal = calendar.HTMLCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY)
```

It prints like that: https://jsfiddle.net/78556w74/

Then in django's template, leave a param like `{{ my_calendar }}`, and when render, `render(request, 'you-html.html', {'my_calendar': myCal})`.